# VB.NET TO C# - Gridview Code behind for a search from a listbox w a stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, gridview, listbox, vb.net-to-c#

I am looking for the correct code behind syntax in C# for displaying Search Results from multiple parameters in Gridview. I just did something similar in VB.NET but I have to update a project in C#.NET and am unsure of:

1) the correct codebehind syntax in C#.NET (code in VB.NET)

2) how to specify multiple search paramaters in the case that a user selects multiple Insurance Plan parameters, Multiple Age parameters, and/or M from a Listbox

3) disable or enable the ability to select multiple parameters in a listbox. (For State and Zip List boxes I'd like to disable selecting multiple parameters and on Plan, Age, and Carrier I'd like to enable selecting multiple parameters.

Here's what I have on the backend in VB.NET that needs to be in C#.NET:

```
      Protected Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
        With Me.SqlDataSource1
        .SelectParameters.Clear()

        .ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PriceFinderConnectionString").ToString
        .SelectCommand = "up_SelectPriceFinderResults" //calling stored procedure 
        .SelectParameters.Add("state_code", Me.lastname.Text)
        .SelectParameters.Add("zip_code", Me.city.Text)
        .SelectParameters.Add("plan_name", Me.state.Text)
        .SelectParameters.Add("age", Me.state.Text)
        .SelectParameters.Add("carrier_name", Me.donotmail.Text)

        .SelectParameters(0).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True
        .SelectParameters(1).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True
        .SelectParameters(2).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True
        .SelectParameters(3).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True
        .SelectParameters(4).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True
        .SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure

        .CancelSelectOnNullParameter = False

    End With

    GridView2.DataBind()
  End Sub
```

Here's the code for the stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_SelectPriceFinderResults] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@state_code varchar(20)= NULL, 
@zip_code varchar(20)= NULL,
     @plan_code varchar(2)= NULL, 
     @insur_age varchar(2)= NULL,
@carrier_name varchar(20)= NULL,

     AS
     BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

IF len(@state_code)=0 
   BEGIN SET @state_code=NULL
   END
IF len(@zip_code)=0
   BEGIN SET @zip_code=NULL 
   END  
IF len(@plan_name)=0
   BEGIN SET @plan_code=NULL
   END
IF len(@insur_age)=0
   BEGIN SET @age=NULL
   END
IF len(@carrier_name)=0
   BEGIN SET @carrier_name=NULL
   END


SELECT  [state_code], 
    [zip_code], 
    [plan_code], 
    [carrier_name],
    [insur_age],  
            [female_value],
    [male_value]        
        CASE WHEN [female_value] is NULL OR 0 
            THEN 'N/A'
        END AS 'female_value',
        CASE WHEN [male_value] is NULL OR 0 
            THEN 'N/A'
        END AS 'male_value',
FROM 
       [state_zipcode_plans] 
WHERE
        (([state_code] = @state_code OR @state_code IS NULL) 
    AND ([zip_code] = @zip_code OR @zip_code IS NULL) 
    AND ([plan_name] = @plan_name OR @plan_name IS NULL) 
    AND ([insur_age] = @insur_age OR @insur_age IS NULL)
    AND ([carrier_name] = @carrier_name OR @carrier_name IS NULL))

ORDER BY 
       [plan_code], [female_value], [male_value]
END
```

Comment: There is no such thing as C#.NET. It's "C#".

Comment: These should have been split out into three completely separate questions.

Comment: @RQDQ, Good Points. I'm a noob haha. The answers I've gotten really haven't solved my problems but have been somewhat helpful. I went ahead an accepted 2 of the most helpful answers for ya. I'll add the stored procedure question to another thread.

Comment: @John Sanders, haha sorry about that, just C# then. Title edited

Comment: @Greg Buehler: I deleted the front end code so that there's less code displayed on there for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There are several ways to approach this:

**Free tools available on line:**

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

**Learn the C# syntax.**

It's not hard, and it's extremely handy to be be able to read C# even if you're primarily working in VB.net because many  of the code samples available on the web are in C#.

2) This is difficult to do with the store procedure approach you have.  You'll either have to just construct dynamic SQL (using [Bind Parameters](http://www.richquackenbush.com/2011/02/bind-variables.html) where possible), or have your stored proc construct and execute the dyanmic sql.

3) This is easy:  Just set the [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of the ListBoxs accordingly.

Comment: When using the VB.NET to C# Converter tool, I got the following error: "-- line 1 col 16: invalid NonModuleDeclaration". Do you have any idea on a fix for that?

Comment: @Brian McCarthy - Is this the only code you have in the file (that's what the error sounds like)?  If that's the case, you'll need to put that code in a class (make sure that it's within the class declaration in your code behind, not just at the very end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Using the converter tool, here's hte code I came up w/ in C#:

```
 protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
var _with1 = this.SqlDataSource1;
_with1.SelectParameters.Clear();

_with1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AgentLeadsConnectionString").ToString;
_with1.SelectCommand = "up_SelectMktDataLeads";
_with1.SelectParameters.Add("state_code", this.state_code.Text);
_with1.SelectParameters.Add("zip_code", this.zip_code.Text);
_with1.SelectParameters.Add("plan_name", this.plan_name.Text);
_with1.SelectParameters.Add("age", this.age.Text);
_with1.SelectParameters.Add("carrier_name", this.carrier_name.Text);

_with1.SelectParameters(0).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
_with1.SelectParameters(1).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
_with1.SelectParameters(2).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
_with1.SelectParameters(3).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
_with1.SelectParameters(4).ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
_with1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;

_with1.CancelSelectOnNullParameter = false;


GridView2.DataBind();
 }
```