# ASP.NET Populate Webforms Listbox based on selection from other Listbox and Database Values + declare scalar variable error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, webforms

I want a listbox to auto-populate zip codes once a state is selected from another listbox based on values defined in the state_zipcode_plans table from the database. 
EX: If the state of FL is selected, load zip_codes (332, 333, 334, 335) where state_code=selected_state_code (FL) into the listbox

I get the error: Must declare the scalar variable @statecode with the existing code.

I was thinking maybe I should put Request.Form("state_code") in there somewhere? 
My friend suggested adding a line in the CS code behind but I'm not sure about the syntax. 
How do I make it work?

Here's the code I have:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ST_Select_ListBox" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DataTextField="state_code" DataValueField="state_code" CssClass="style7"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PriceFinderConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [state_code] FROM [state_code] ORDER BY [state_code]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="NULL" FormField="state_code" Name="state_code" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

```
             <td class="style2"> <span class="style7">Select Zip (auto-populated based on selected State)
                                </span>
                                <br class="style7" />
<br class="style7" />
<asp:ListBox ID="Zip_Select_ListBox" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CssClass="style7">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PriceFinderConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [zip_code] FROM [state_zipcode_plans] WHERE ([state_code] = @state_code)" Request.Form("state_code")>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="NULL" FormField="zip_code" Name="zip_code" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's the codebehind in C#:

```
    protected void Search_STZipPlan_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand searchPF = new SqlCommand("up_SelectPriceFinderResults", conn); //calling stored procedure 
        searchPF.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =  new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder["Data Source"] = "SqlDataSource1";
        builder["integrated Security"] = true;
        builder["Initial Catalog"] = "PriceFinder;NewValue=Bad";
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);

        SqlParameter state_code = new SqlParameter("state_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3); 
        SqlParameter zip_code = new SqlParameter("zip_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6); 
        SqlParameter plan_name = new SqlParameter("plan_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16);

        // SqlDataReader reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // Search_Results_GridView.DataSource = reader;

        Search_Results_GridView.DataBind();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET TO C# - Gridview Code behind for a search from a listbox w a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031458/vb-net-to-c-gridview-code-behind-for-a-search-from-a-listbox-w-a-stored-proced)

Comment: isn't this a duplicate question?

Comment: @John Saunders: No, it's a different question but it's on the same project. My previous question was asking how to write the syntax of the code-behind in C# and didn't use a stored procedure at that point.  In this question, I'm asking about the error- Must declare the scalar variable

Comment: then you really need to make it clearer why this isn't a duplicate. the fact that you posted the same code doesn't make it any easier to see the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is SQL related. There probably is a mistake in the stored procedure

```
 up_SelectPriceFinderResults
```

Since I don't See the stored procedure's source code, I presume you forgot to declare a parameter or a variable. You'll have to declare the variable @state_code inside your stored procedure:

```
 declare @state_code varchar(3)
```

or as a parameter of the stored procedure. Anyway, check the source code of the stored procedure:

```
exec sp_helptext up_SelectPriceFinderResults
```

Comment: Thanks splattne, for your response! Where do I put declare @state_code varchar(3) in the codebehind? To clarify, what i'm trying to do, here's an example: If the state of FL is selected in the listbox, zip_codes (332, 333, 334, 335) load into zip code list box where state_code (from table) =selected_state_code (from listbox) (FL)

Comment: You have view/edit the SQL code to on your SQL Server instance in "Stored Procedures."